# Setting Java Path in Ubuntu

Tags: java

I have set my JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME in bashrc. This is how i have set,

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

But when i give

```
java -version
```

I get this error,

```
-bash: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

I have checked the permission of **/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java** which was **755**. I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: Maybe a 64bit Java on a 32bit operating system?

Comment: Are you using the correct binaries for ubuntu?

Comment: It seems like this question might be better fitted for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) since it is not directly programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

the OS is 32-bit and tried to install 64-bit jdk.

type:  file /sbin/init that will give you the right OS (32/64) and then install the correct one via Java.com

Answer (score -1):

Instead of set this way:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Try to set like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91
export JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

If it does not work in bashrc, set in **~/.profile**